# Unable to connect MQTT client to AWS IoT using ATWINC1500

Tags: mqtt, aws-iot, pic32

Requesting assistance on how to securely connect to AWS IoT MQTT broker on port 8883 using ATWINC1500. As I understand from documentation, 3 things are required:

1. Private key
2. Client certificate
3. Root certificate

I have created a 'thing' in AWS IoT Core, downloaded it's keys, certificate and flashed the private key and certificate to ATWINC1500 using below command

```
tls_cert_flash_tool.exe Write -key ../../../tls_cert_store/xxx.key -cert ../../../tls_cert_store/xxx.pem.crt -erase
```

This gets updated successfully, and I can read and confirm the same.
[image]

I have flashed all root certificates for AWS + Mosquitto test broker using below command

```
root_certificate_downloader.exe -n 6 ../binary/AmazonRootCA1.pem ../binary/AmazonRootCA3.pem ../binary/G2-RootCA1.pem ../binary/G2-RootCA3.pem ../binary/SFSRootCAG2.pem ../binary/mosquitto.org.crt -no_wait -port 0 -e
```

[image]

Same code is used to connect with test.mosquitto.org and my AWS endpoint on port 8883. Connections works fine with mosquitto broker (it does not require client certificate), while it is denied/fails with AWS IoT. I am receiving error code as -12 on received socket.

Can someone share an example or a document on how to identify certificate installation and secure connection using ATWINC1500 ? Am I missing something here or doing something wrong ?

Below is my hardware and software configuration
Mirco-controller: PIC32MZ2048EFM100
Harmony: v2.06
FreeRTOS: v10
ATWINC1500 Firmware: 19.5.2

Thanks,
Karan

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the batch file in "src" folder instead of typing the commands.
You should allocate the 3 RSA files in the right folder before and rename them as required by the batch file.